# Get element value based on sibling value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml which looks as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FieldValueCollection xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Item>
    <Name>requestid</Name>
    <Value>123456</Value>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>objectid</Name>
    <Value>abcdefg</Value>
  </Item>
</FieldValueCollection>
```

Using xslt (I am complete newb at this so apologies) how can I get the value of the Value element when given the Name value requestid ?

My latest attempt at this is

```
<xsl:value-of select="/FieldValueCollection/Item/Name/@value='requestid'/../Value/@value"/>
```

Comment: with "@" you only address attributes. Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the path `/FieldValueCollection/Item[Name = 'requestid']/Value`.